# Authorization Access denied while accessing Azure Active Directory

Tags: python, azure-active-directory

I am using below code :

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

app_id = '9a48d65b-XXXXXXXXX' #Application Id - on the azure app overview page
client_secret = 'loOBJ9=-XXXXXXX' 
#Use the redirect URL to create a token url
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/1ab41d5a-XXX-4af0-XXXXX-e3c54d03997b/oauth2/token'
token_data = {
 'grant_type': 'password',
 'client_id': app_id,
 'client_secret': client_secret,
 'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
 'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com',
 'username':'abc@company.com', #Account with no 2MFA
 'password':'XXXXXXX!',
}
token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
token = token_r.json().get('access_token')

print(token_r.content)

users_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=500'

headers = {
 'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)
}
user_response_data = json.loads(requests.get(users_url, headers=headers).text)

print(user_response_data)
# user_response_data[‘@odata.nextLink’]
#initial user data
#get all users
for user in user_response_data['value']:
 userId.append(user['id'])
 displayName.append(user['displayName'])
 mailAddress.append(user['userPrincipalName'])

users_dict = {'userId':userId,'displayName':displayName,'mailAddress':mailAddress}
users_df = pd.DataFrame(data=users_dict)
#additional user query for paging
while '@odata.nextLink' in user_response_data:
 user_response_data = json.loads(requests.get(users_url, headers=headers).text)
 if '@odata.nextLink' in user_response_data: 
    users_url = user_response_data['@odata.nextLink']

 for user in user_response_data['value']:
    userId.append(user['id'])
    displayName.append(user['displayName'])
    mailAddress.append(user['userPrincipalName'])

users_dict = {'userId':userId,'displayName':displayName,'mailAddress':mailAddress}
users_df = pd.DataFrame(data=users_dict)
users_df.head()
```

But,i am getting below error:
b'{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"offline_access openid profile User.Read","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"3599","expires_on":"1580421349","not_before":"1580417449","resource":"https://graph.microsoft.com","access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Il
{'error': {'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied', 'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', 'innerError': {'request-id': '4fc27125-8960-44e6-9510-e3cfca8bce7f', 'date': '2020-01-30T20:55:50'}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sNowDelete.py", line 35, in 
    for user in user_response_data['value']:
KeyError: 'value'

Please help.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: @TonyJu Nope, Still same error.

Comment: I just noticed that you have `User.Read` permission, but no `User.Read.All` permission in the error message you provided. Have you added User.Read.All permission and granted admin consent?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have enough privileges. Please go to Azure portal to check your permissions. You should have `User.Read.All` **delegated** permission.

[image]

Also, this permission needs grant admin consent. You need to click **Grant admin consent** button and sign in with the admin account to grant admin consent.

Comment: Admin account == global admin / application admin / cloud application admin.